# multiple ng-switch-when condition only rendering one DOM angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

so I created some experiment based on my project..

I create a rendering condition using `ng-switch` angularjs directive

this is the controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];

  $scope.test = $scope.items[0];

});
```

meanwhile, this is the html element

```
<select ng-model="test" ng-options="item for item in items"></select>
    <div ng-switch="test">
      <div ng-switch-when="test1">this is test 1</div>
      <div ng-switch-when="test2">this is test 2</div>
      <div ng-switch-when="test3">this is test 3</div>
      <div ng-switch-when="test3">this is test 3</div>
    </div>
```

as you could see when I changed the select box, it supposed to render the dom based on the selection of the selectbox, the strange thing is that when I select the value 'test3' only one element renders while what I want is both of the 'test3' ng-swith-when condition rendered

and the documentation clearly states that

> the case statement to match against. If match then this case will be
>   displayed. If the same match appears multiple times, all the elements
>   will be displayed.

how do I fixed this ? anyone care to elaborate ?

this is the [**plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1MdtwPViRXODMrrLEKRt) work test

**note that I used angularjs version 1.0.7 and I don't want to change the version**

Answer (score 0):

What your reading is from the new version of the docs for angularjs, here's the old:

https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/docs/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch

vs the new:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Loading up the change log for 1.1.3 is where they added it:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1.1.3

So to fix your issue, simply wrap the content in a single div:

```
<div ng-switch="test">
  <div ng-switch-when="test1">this is test 1</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="test2">this is test 2</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="test3">
        <div>this is test 3</div>
        <div>this is test 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```